# Why does the Solar in Pathfinder have +10 Con and +2 Wis compared to the 3.5 version?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, conversion

I've read every single conversion guide and rules system that I could find to explain these kinds of changes, and I've found nothing at all.

I'm trying to convert a ton of 3.5 creatures to PF, but with these kinds of anomalies in the conversion, I feel like I may be missing a rule.

Balors got +5 Con out of nowhere. Solars got +10 Con out of nowhere it seems, and I try explaining it away with HD, Type, and other things but simply cannot explain it.

Are these exceptions and not rules? Did they just give Solars a +120 HP boost to provide a greater challenge or make them on par with other CR 23 things?

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard-and-fast set of rules for converting monsters from 3.5 to Pathfinder.  One of the explicit design goals of Pathfinder was to rebalance the game - as [Paizo puts it](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/rpg):

> the Pathfinder RPG is designed to smooth over a number of the rough spots in the 3.5 rules set

Thus, when making Pathfinder versions of 3.5 content, the designers felt free to make balance changes as they saw fit, and did so in many cases.

So, in short, **the Solar in Pathfinder has higher stats than in 3.5 because the designers of Pathfinder thought it should.**  When converting creatures from 3.5 to Pathfinder, you should feel free to make such changes yourself, or not, based on the needs of your game.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I like having neat and orderly rules systems to use, but I thought it might have been that the designers simply wanted to buff them or something.

My main issue is that I don't want to add something like Beholders, or something less dramatic like Illithid and get the balancing wrong. If they are pathetic compared to Pathfinder PCs, I'm better off playing 3.5.

Comment: @ConfusedGuy PF PCs are about as strong as 3.5 PCs.  There are some balance changes between the systems, but nothing drastic enough that PCs in one system are universally way stronger than the other.  So, when importing a monster from 3.5 to PF without changes, you can rely on it being a well-balanced challenge to the same extent you could in 3.5 (i.e., not much because the CR system is very unreliable).  If you have specific questions about balance concerns when importing a given monster, I'd recommend asking that as a new question.